# Create a S3 bucket policy to restrict access based on access key for private cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops

this scenario is for private cloud in on-premise. we have multiple buckets in a single tenant. we generate access key & secret key for individual buckets in the same tenant. i want to use bucket policy to grant access to bucket based on access-key and deny access for the remaining buckets in the tenant.

Comment: Since its client that is going to write data to S3 Bucket. I don’t want to go the IAM way. And it’s an on premise private cloud, we want to avoid IAM role/policy management as it’s not robust like AWS. I am still keen to explore the access based on access-key? (Am also open to suggestions) –
Just to rephrase it’s not IAM key, rather I intend to use tenant access key/credentials to validate bucket access.
's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,

Comment: I am confused. You say "private cloud" but you also mention S3. So is it using AWS, or is it not?

Comment: John, its private cloud. we have AWS S3 as PAS. we offer s3 buckets to store data. the bucket is mounted on UNIX hosts, and application write data .

Comment: So when you say that you have "AWS S3", you really mean an S3-compatible service that does _not_ use the real "Amazon S3"? If so, does that S3-compatible service support an IAM-compatible service?

Comment: es, S3 compatible services. yes we do support IAM. we want to avoid IAM role/policy management as its not robust like AWS. I am still keen to explore the access based on access-key?

Comment: It's somewhat hard to offer recommendations for a system that isn't AWS and doesn't necessarily work like AWS. I think you're on your own here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via IAM key, but you can via the principal which in this case is the IAM user.

Using the `NotPrincipal` you can exclusive deny permissions to anyone who is not the IAM user(s) referenced. Use this with to care to prevent accidentally blocking yourself from being able to manage the bucket.

Below is an example of a bucket policy using this

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "statement1",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/$USERNAME"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:Put*",
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
            "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Sid": "statement1",
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/$USERNAME"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:Put*",
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
            "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Chris, appreciate the input. Since its client that is going to write data to S3 Bucket. I don’t want to go the IAM way. And it’s an on premise private cloud, we want to avoid IAM role/policy management as its not robust like AWS.
I am still keen to explore the access based on access-key? (Am also open to suggestions)

Comment: Chris, Just to rephrase it’s not IAM key, rather I intend to use tenant access key/credentials to validate bucket access.

Comment: What type of access do they require?

Comment: alloow s3:PutObjectTagging
s3:PutObject
s3:GetObjectTagging
s3:GetObject
s3:DeleteObject
s3:DeleteObjectTagging